# Explain the convolutions of setp function

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, convolution

$$ t* u(t-a)= \frac{1}{2}(t-a)^2 u(t-a)$$

attempt:

$$ t* u(t-a)= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} tu(t-a)dt$$

I don't quiet understand what i write before. What mean that t is a causal function?

$$ t* u(t-a)= \int_{0}^{t} (t-\tau)u(\tau-a)d\tau $$

$$ t* u(t-a) = \frac{1}{2} (t-a)^2...$$

Comment: When you convolve there should be an additional variable for the argument of the convolution (since the convolution is itself a function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
\begin{align}
f(t)&=u(t-a)\\
g(t)&=t\\
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
f(t)*g(t)&=\int_{0}^{t}f(\tau)g(t-\tau)d\tau\\
&=\int_{0}^{t} u(\tau-a)(t-\tau)d\tau\\
&=\int_{a}^{t}(t-\tau)d\tau \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{assuming}(t\ge a)\\ 
&=-\frac{1}{2}(t-\tau)^2\biggl|_a^t u(t-a)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}(t-a)^2 u(t-a)  
\end{align}